# XCode - Adding Local swift packages in the application target using xcconfig file

Tags: swift, xcode, xcconfig, swift-package, xcode-build-settings

I have a white-label project which has multiple app targets. All the target use the common code and their specific assets.
All the common code is divided into Core Modules and Feature Modules. All of these modules are Local Swift packages in the project.
All app targets include the Core Modules and include feature modules as required (Some app targets don't need certain features). All the app targets build settings are configured using XCConfig files, CI pipelines are appropriately set up to use the correct scheme to build, archive, and upload the correct app to TestFlight.

For each app target, we have to add the local swift packages in `Target->General->Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content`. This is a repetitive process for each new app target we add (Which is not very often but still it's a manual process). I would want to achieve this by XCConfig file where all the Core Packages will be included in Base.xcconfig and feature packages will be in Target-specific xcconfig files.

Can someone point out what would be the right build Setting to look for linking these local swift packages?

Comment: have you figured this out? if so, please add an answer